# How to Configure Membase?

Tags: nosql, membase

After searching about Cassandra a little bit, i wanted to learn about Membase NoSql. I downloaded it but i couldn't find a way to configure it. Is there anyone who can help me ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the current version (beta 2) there isn't much configuration to do.  With the exception of a per-server memory quota, everything should be setup by default.

Once you install, you should be able to immediately talk "memcached" over port 11211 to the Membase server.  Both ASCII and binary protocols are supported.

Beta 3 will introduce multiple buckets, the ability to set memory and disk quotas per bucket as well as the replica count per bucket.

Let me know if you have any other questions, you can also visit forums.northscale.com.

Thanks, take care.

Perry